# How to change ToggleButton from ViewModel?

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, silverlight, togglebutton

I came across an interesting issue.

Summary: I can't change the state of a toggle button from the ViewModel. The same problem seems to be with Microsoft ToggleButton as well as Telerik Controls.

**ViewModel:**

```
private bool? _isToggleChecked;
public bool? IsToggleChecked
{
    get { return _isToggleChecked; }
    set
    {
        if(_isToggleChecked == value)
            return;
        _isToggleChecked = value;
        RaisePropertyChanged(()=>IsToggleChecked);
    }
}

public VM()
{
    FireCommand = new DelegateCommand(OnFire);
}

private void OnFire()
{
    if (IsToggleChecked == null)
    {
        IsToggleChecked = true;
        return;
    }

    IsToggleChecked = !IsToggleChecked;
}

public DelegateCommand FireCommand { get; set; }
```

**View: (Microsoft ToggleButton could be used instead with the same behavior)**

```xml
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="White">
    <StackPanel>
        <telerik:RadToggleButton Height="50" IsChecked="{Binding IsToggleChecked}" />
        <Button Command="{Binding FireCommand}" Height="20" />
    </StackPanel>        
</Grid>
```

**View Code Behind:**

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = new VM();
}
```

How is this possible? How can I change the toggle state programmaticaly?

Many Thanks,

Comment: did you try do not use Nullable property?

Comment: Thank you, that works now. :) Please put this there as response and I mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To me this is a `Nullable` property problem, that **telerik** control doesn't support for some reason. If so, check on provider's site for available solutions/ service packs or simply make your property *NON* `Nullable` and refactor your code.

Regards.

Answer (score 2):

I had a problem with binding IsChecked on a RadRibbonToggleButton when I had the button bound to a command.

The workaround I found was to use a two way binding, but prevent the binding updating the source by using UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit

```
IsChecked="{Binding IsLocked, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=Explicit}"
```

This works for me.

It is described as a known issue in WPF [here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/wpf/thread/6357ac1f-42aa-4887-9fcb-36561f0e40c4)